# Pandas joining strings in a column according to consecutive values in another

Tags: python, pandas

I have two cols in a DataFrame col1 and col2 and I need to generate result column.
Every FD has few correlated MS that are supposed to be populated in the result column as shown in the fig

[image]

```
dict_obj = {'col1': ['FD', 'MS', 'MS', 'FD', 'MS', 'MS', 'MS', 'FD', 'MS', 'MS'], 
            'col2': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_obj)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy.agg`, join your strings and assign it back to the "FD" rows:

```
grp = (df.assign(col3=(df['col1'] == 'FD').cumsum())
         .query("col1 == 'MS'")
         .groupby('col3')['col2'].agg('|'.join))
df.loc[df['col1'] == 'FD', 'result'] = grp.values # grp.to_numpy(); pandas >= 0.24

df
  col1 col2 result
0   FD    A    B|C
1   MS    B    NaN
2   MS    C    NaN
3   FD    D  E|F|G
4   MS    E    NaN
5   MS    F    NaN
6   MS    G    NaN
7   FD    H    I|J
8   MS    I    NaN
9   MS    J    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

- use (df["col1"]=="FD").cumsum() to group rows by "FD"s count
- for each group join values of col2 except the 1st one
- assign the values to "result" column of row with "FD" in col1

```py
df["result"] = ""
df.loc[df["col1"]=="FD", "result"] = df.groupby((df["col1"]=="FD").cumsum()) \
.apply(lambda group: group["col2"][1:].str.cat(sep="|")).values

df
```